# Unity - How to check if there is a Tile of an specific Tilemap in the position x,y,z

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made 4 TileMaps in the same Grid
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csr5Q.png]

Lvl1 = The Level Blocks/Tiles,
Lvl1 Dec = The Decoration of the Level,
Negative Parts = Parts where the Player cant Jump,
Positive Parts = [The red ones]Parts where the player stops the jump Animation

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GVKi.png]

So that the thing is I want to check if there is a Positive Tile in a specific Position of that Tilemap, but my code does just checks for Colliders

```
if (TileChanger == Grass)
{
    Vector3 pos = Cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
    RaycastHit2D hitdown = Physics2D.Raycast(vecdown, Vector2.zero);
    if (hitdown != false && hitdown.collider != null)
    {
        PositiveParts.SetTile(vecInt, Positive);
        PositiveParts.SetTile(vecIntdown, null);
    }
    else
    {
        PositiveParts.SetTile(vecInt, Positive);
    }
}
```

So is there any code to get an specific Tile from a specific Tilemap?

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use the gameObject property of the collider to get the tile?

```
hitdown.collider.gameObject
```

Then check to see if this is a positive tile using your own validation.

EDIT:

If you just want a tile at a specific coordinate, you can use the Tilemap.GetTile method. Documentation can be found here:
[Tilemap.GetTile](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Tilemaps.Tilemap.GetTile.html)

Comment: Why not? If you can confirm that the gameObject is equal to the positiveparts tilemap, then you know that you've hit a positive tile?

Comment: Oh, now I understand, that could help me, if I get what I want I'll tell you, thank you man!

Comment: No problem, definitely let me know! And welcome to SO!